# Peewee: simple where condition that is always True

Tags: python, peewee

I would like to do something like this:

```
conditions = Model.attribute == Model.attribute
conditions &= (more conditions here)

Model.select().where(conditions)
```

Is there something similar to [Django's Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to replace the first line?

Comment: Do you mean `True`? (Note that it's possible to write a custom `__eq__` method that doesn't produce reasonable results.)

Comment: I just want an object that I can pass to .where() that produces the same results as not passing anything. I tried True, but that throws an error because it's not a peewee expression.

Comment: An equality check returns either `True` or `False` - I'm not sure why a longer expression that evaluates to `True` would work but `True` itself wouldn't.

Comment: Have you used peewee?

Comment: It seems that passing object that is `None` gives the same results as not passing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get such condition using the following expression:

```
from peewee import Value
...

def TRUE_condition():
   return (Value(1) == Value(1))

...
conditions = TRUE_condition()
conditions &= (Model.attribute == 42)
Model.select().where(conditions)
```

However this might look like a hack. A more elegant solution is to collect all  conditions in a list and then `reduce` them with the `and` operator:

```
from functools import reduce
from peewee import operator

conditions = list()
conditions.append(Model.attribute == 42)
conditions.append(Model.active == True)
condition = reduce(operator.and_, conditions)
Model.select().where(condition)
```

Comment: Using `reduce` is the peewee-approved way to do it.

Comment: Just saw this comment and just wanted to say thanks for Peewee @coleifer! Have been using it over several years now, across different projects and companies.

Comment: @kev do you want to mark my answer as a solution for the problem, since the author of the lib approved it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `True` is working :

```
conditions = True
conditions &= (Model.attribute == 42)
Model.select().where(conditions)
```